# Store information from forms in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I am a beginner in flutter and I am trying to create a medicine tracker app. I want to know how I can store user input in the form of class objects. I have created a form that accepts the name of the pill and time as checkbox values - morning, afternoon, evening and night.
After the user provides this information I want to store it as an object and that object in a list.
I later want to use it to create containers that display the name of the pill and time it needs to be taken.
I have created a separate class. How do I store user input as class object?

here is the class file -

```
class MedInfo{
  late String name;
  late List<bool> medTime;

  MedInfo(String n,List<bool> t){
    name=n;
    medTime=t;
  }
}
```

Here is the input page code-

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'listItem.dart';
import 'medInfo.dart';

class MedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MedPageState createState()=> _MedPageState();
}

class _MedPageState extends State<MedPage> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey= GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<MedInfo> items=[]; //maintains pills

  Future<MedInfo> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context) async{
    return await showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (context) {
      final TextEditingController customController= TextEditingController();

      bool isMorning = false;
      bool isAfternoon= false;
      bool isEvening=false;
      bool isNight=false;
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context,setState){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Name of the Pill"),
          content: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: customController,
                    // validator: (value){
                    //   return value.isNotEmpty ? null : "Invalid Field";
                    // },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter name of the medicine"),
                  ),
                  Text("Choice Box"),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [

                      Text("Morning"),

                      Checkbox(
                          //title: Text("Morning"),
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          //fillColor: Colors.pink,

                          value: isMorning,
                          onChanged: (bool? checked){
                            setState((){
                              isMorning = checked!;
                            });
                          }),
                        ],
                      ),
                   Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                       children: [

                       Text("Afternoon"),

                        Checkbox(
            //title: Text("Morning"),
                            checkColor: Colors.white,
              //fillColor: Colors.pink,

                            value: isAfternoon,
                            onChanged: (bool? checked){
                              setState((){
                           isAfternoon = checked!;
                        });
                         }),
            ],
        ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [

                      Text("Evening"),

                      Checkbox(
                        //title: Text("Morning"),
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          //fillColor: Colors.pink,

                          value: isEvening,
                          onChanged: (bool? checked){
                            setState((){
                              isEvening = checked!;
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [

                      Text("Night"),

                      Checkbox(
                        //title: Text("Morning"),
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          //fillColor: Colors.pink,

                          value: isNight,
                          onChanged: (bool? checked){
                            setState((){
                              isNight = checked!;
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              )
              )
          ),
          // content: TextField(
          //   controller: customController,
          // ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Text("OK"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(customController.text.toString()); // to go back to screen after submitting
                }
            )

          ],
        );
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My med app'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget> [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return ReusableListItem(Color(0xFFd2fddf),items[index].name);
                },
                itemCount: items.length,


              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),

      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          print("Clicked");
          showInformationDialog(context).then((onValue){
            print(onValue);

            setState(() {
              items.add(onValue);

            });
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

TextFormField also has an option of `onChanged` which allows you to set a callback which is called every time when there is a change in the text field.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes
Check this for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do this,
I am mentioning both see what suits your needs:-

#1. You can use **onFieldSubmitted** and pass callback like this...

```
TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'pill name'),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a name!';
                  }
                },
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          
                    pillName = value;
                  
                },
              ),
```

You can also create a object for your form and then everytime you need to save data just make an instance and call like:-

```
 onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    formObject.pillName = value;
                  });
                },
```

and if you are wondering how to submit a form then you have to just add a button inside the form widget.

Here is an interactive example => [click me to see an example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)

#2. if you want to access the data before the form submitted then you have to make **TextEditingController** for each field.

and [click](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input) to see interactive example of **textEditingController**.

Happy coding...